# I have to use a command in shell script which will give a prompt for Y or N.How do i answer it as Y in shell script afater the command

Tags: scripts

```
$ command
Are you sure you want to set cOrders to be Y? <Y/N> Y
```

How to i do the answering as Y in shell script

Comment: some commands have a flag for yes, which command and what OS are you running?

Comment: Many shell commands can be run with `-y` parameter. That will mean `yes`.

Answer (score 2):

In the simplest form, you can just `echo` a `Y` to the command:

```
echo "Y" | command
```

Alternatively, if it will give you multiple prompts and you want to answer `Y` to all of them, use `yes`:

```
yes | command
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pipe the `yes` command to automatically answer yes.
The command below will automatically answer yes to apt-gets request to install.

```
yes | apt-get upgrade
```